# Store question IDs with response types in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I have a survey application. the user enters the survey title and a number of questions, and with each question, there is a response type that the user chooses based on his needs. In my backend, I need to store in my database with each response type the user chooses a corresponding questionID in order to retrieve questions with their equivalent response types.

*The problem is: in my Laravel controller code, the same questionId is stored with all response types instead of one questionID with each.*

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $inputCount = $request->input_count;
    $totalQuetions = $request->question_id;

    if (is_string($totalQuetions)) 
    {
        $totalQuetions = explode(',', $totalQuetions);
    } else {
        $totalQuetions = (array) $totalQuetions;
    }

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($totalQuetions);  $j++) 
    {
        $inputTypes = [
            'one_tenvalues' => $request->input('one_tenvalues'),
            'starsvalues' => $request->input('starsvalues'),
            'persentagevalues' => $request->input('persentagevalues'),
            'textvalues' => $request->input('textvalues'),
            'emojivalues' => $request->input('emojivalues'),
        ];
        $inputCount = $request->input('input_count');
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $inputCount; $i++) {
            $inputName = 'input_' . $i;
            $inputTypes[$inputName] = $request->input($inputName);
        }

        // loop through the input types and create a new QuestionReponseType for each one
        foreach ($inputTypes as $inputType => $inputValue) {
            if (!empty($inputValue)) {
                $jsonData = json_encode($inputValue);
                $questionReponseType = new QuestionReponseType();
                $questionReponseType->values = $jsonData;
          // here where I need To attach question_id with each iteration
                $questionReponseType->question_id = $totalQuetions[$j];
                
                $questionReponseType->save();
            }
        }
    }

    return view('home');
```